# How do I write my code to reverse the motors in the opposite direction so the RSLK can move backwards?

Tags: arduino-mega, motor, joystick

I've assembled the TI RSLK Robot Maze Edition for a final project for my embedded systems class. Instead of using the MSP432P401R LaunchPad that came with the kit to control the power board, I've used an Arduino MEGA 2560 instead. I'm also using a KY-023 Analog Joystick to control the two dc motors.

```
int xPin = A0; // analog input for x-axis joystick
int yPin = A1; // analog input for y-axis joystick

int yPosition = 0;
int xPosition = 0;

//Right motor pins
#define MRSpeed 11
#define MRDir 10
#define MRSleep 9

//Left motor pins
#define MLSpeed 8
#define MLDir 7
#define MLSleep 6


void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(xPin, INPUT); // setup x input
 pinMode(yPin, INPUT); // setup y input

 pinMode(MRSpeed, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(MRDir, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(MRSleep, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(MRSleep, 1);

 pinMode(MLSpeed, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(MLDir, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(MLSleep, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(MLSleep, 1);

 }

 void loop() {

  yPosition = analogRead(yPin);
  xPosition = analogRead(xPin);

  //Steer Forward
  if (yPosition > 1020)
  {
    analogWrite(MRSpeed, 255); //To move right wheel forward
    analogWrite(MLSpeed, 255); //To move left wheel forward
  }

   //To stop both wheels
    else if (yPosition = 506 || 505)
    {
      analogWrite(MRSpeed, 0);
      analogWrite(MLSpeed,0);
    }

     //Turn Right
      if(xPosition < 512)
      {
       analogWrite(MRSpeed, 0);
       analogWrite(MLSpeed, 255);
      }

     //Turn Left
       if(xPosition > 1020)
       {
         analogWrite(MRSpeed, 255);
         analogWrite(MLSpeed, 0);
       }


       }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use those `MRDir`/`MLDir` outputs?

Comment: And also: `(yPosition = 506 || 505)` won't work as you hope it'll

Comment: @KIIV I've added                                                                                                
   else if (yPosition < 505)
   {
    digitalWrite(MRDir, HIGH);
    analogWrite(MRSpeed,255);
    } But I get no movement

Comment: @Angel Please update the code in your question, if you change something, so that we can exactly see, what you changed.